# Can a non-us citizen grandparent apply for US citizen child's passport?

Tags: united-states, family-law, passport

If US citizen's child's parents, are at work abroad.
US citizen child is staying with grand-parent in US. 
Grandparents are on temporary 6 months visit visa.

1) Can grand-parent apply for passport of US citizen grandchild ?

2) Does grand-parent need to be appointed as legal guardian ?

3) Can US child leave the country with a grand-parent to go to his/her parent ?

Note: Grandparent / nor Parents are US citizens nor do they reside in US (non-residents)

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Travel.SE], or maybe [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.  See the State Department's page on passports for [children under 16](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/under-16.html).  If both parents are unable to appear

> A third party may apply for the child's passport with a notarized statement from both parents/guardians giving that third party permission to apply for the child.
>
> The statement must include a photocopy of the parents/guardians' identification.

2. No.  See above for details.
3. Yes.  A notarized letter of consent from both parents may be necessary depending on where the parents are.